# Weighted entropy using similarity scores

Tags: entropy, similarities, frequency

I have a list (`freq`) of letters with the following frequencies:

```
         L          V          Q          I 
0.61764706 0.29411765 0.05882353 0.02941176
```

The entropy of this list is: `-sum(freq * log2(freq))` = 1.3387

I would like a statistic similar to entropy that takes into account a pairwise "similarity" score of these letters, rather than just frequency. Here is the similarity score matrix (`smat`):

```
   L  V  Q  I
L  6  1 -4  2
V  1  7 -4  4
Q -4 -4  9 -5
I  2  4 -5  7
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the sum of the dot product of the similarity matrix with the frequency vector dot frequency prime `sum(smat . freq . freq')` (quadratic form) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Use f'Sf to get you a quadratic score, you can see it as x^2 terms and xy mixed terms weighting pairwise comparisons

Comment: @ThreeDiag can you elaborate please? what is the calculation you propose with the terms above?

Comment: f is your frequency vector. The calculation is vector matrix vector product , look up quadratic form. It returns you a quadratic function of the vector weighted by elements of the matrix S and should be a good start. If you want to generalise entropy you might consider something like f=freq * log(freq) and again f'Sf. It will weight highly high entropy, high weight elements.

Comment: @ThreeDiag thanks! I modified the answer to reflect that